# Where to store data gathered by applet?

Tags: java, applet

I am writing my first real applet and I need to store some data. I've never really messed with putting and maintaining code on the internet, so please bear with me if I'm a little slow to catch on.

I'm building a Calendar applet for work (just a student worker) and I'm not sure how to store necessary information such as the schedules for certain days and login name and password information. I assume I have access to a server and such, but I don't know exactly what I would traditionally need or what I would need to do with what I need.

In the worst case scenario, I could simply put the information into text files and read them on every start-up where the applet is stored, but that definitely seems like a very wrong way of doing things. Can you guys educate me on a few practical ways people accomplish this in the real world. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Options that are free/open source would be best.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this sort of small application, I would go for SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

How about a relational database such as SQL Server ?  Maybe access?